# Monitor Crystal Reports server

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-server

We have Crystal Reports server, and we have a service in our system that sends schedule reports. That Crystal Reports is working against Oracle server.

We found that when Oracle is down, the service (that listens to port 6400) also comes down and we need to restart the Crystal services once Oracle server is back.

Is there a way to report when Crystal Server is down? And most importantly, is there a way that it will come back up when Oracle server is back online automatically?

Thanks

Comment: What version of crystal reports server do you have?

Comment: @Kristof Crystal Server 2013

Answer (score 0):

Log on to the CMC using the Administrator account, then select the *Servers* option, and look for the CMS server (categorised under *Core servers*). If you open the properties for the CMS server, you should see the option *Auto Reconnect to System Database*. The administrator documentation explains this options as follows:

> Specifies whether the CMS automatically attempts to rees­tablish a
>   connection to the CMS database in the event of a service disruption.
>   If this value is set to FALSE, you are able to check the integrity of
>   the CMS database before resuming operations; you must restart the CMS
>   to reestablish the da­tabase connection.

By default this option is enabled.

There are several option you can use **to check** if your CMS is still working:

- Check if the server is still accepting network connections on port 6400
- Use the command-line version of the CCM and check its output. The command-line options are detailed in SAP KB [1733907](https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1733907) - *How to manage servers from command line in BI 4.0 in a Windows environment?*
- Run the *CMS database connection* probe and check its output. SAP KB [1670183](https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1670183) describes how to run the probe on the command-line (about halfway in the article); SAP KB [1576032](https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1576032) describes this probe as:

> […] test[s] the availability of the repository database by executing a query
>   to return the system Info Object representing the cluster name. The
>   CMS retrieves it from the database; hence a failure is likely to
>   indicate a connection problem between the CMS and the database.

Comment: Hi, I checked that setting - it was already checked to Auto Reconnect